# LDAP Authentication failed for Citrix Netscaler showing ("Error: '10.0.1.4' is a valid LDAP server. Valid Credentials are not provided)

Tags: ldap, citrix, netscaler

I have tried every possible method starting from checking connection to resetting password with no special characters.

Couldn't solve the error of *Invalid credentials* in Citrix ADC 13.0 .

While adding LDAP authentication servers facing the same error over and over again. Have verified the account name, Base DN, Administrator Bind DN but nothing seems to work.

- Server '10.0.1.4' is reachable.
- port '389/tcp' is open.
- '10.0.1.4' is a valid LDAP server.
- Valid Credentials are not provided.

Even I could successfully bind from *ldp.exe* with simple auth (not using SSL) using the same creds. DC running on Windows Server 2016.
Base DN (location of users)*= CN=Users,DC=#####,DC=local
Administrator Bind DN* = CN=useradmin,CN=Users,DC=#####,DC=local

Answer (score 0):

I had to contact Citrix technical support to get this resolved. He had me downgrade Netscaler to version 13.0.71.44 which fixed the issue. He said it was only a bug in the GUI but I have my doubts. I was originally at 13.0.79.64.

Comment: yes it is a bug in the GUI